# SQLite - Database Locked when trying to set PRAGMA synchronous = OFF

Tags: sqlite

So here is the scenario: We are adding a VACUUM routine and this appears to be working as expected. However, the journal file is not being removed unless we exit out of the application entirely. After googling many times, we tried a suggestion: after the VACUUM is completed we inserted a "**connection.close**" and then a "**connection.open**" process hoping this would remove the journal file as was reported in the google reads.

We have two PRAGMA statements when connecting to available Databases:
"PRAGMA synchronous = OFF" and 
"PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE"

These work fine when opening up and initially connecting to a SQLite DB.

However, when trying to "**re-connect**" as part of the process mentioned above after VACCUUM this "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF" statement results in a "Database Locked" error. The "PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE" does not produce an error.

Any insight into this would be appreciated.